# FullCalendar not Displaying Events Correctly

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am having trouble with the FullCalendar js library not displaying events correctly.  I'm not sure what the issue is as I have followed the instructions on their introduction page, but the events are always displayed at the very bottom of the calendar and are never 'inline' with the times.

```
<html>
    <head>
       <meta charset='utf-8' />
       <link rel="stylesheet" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.3.1/fullcalendar.min.css" type="text/css" />
       <!--<link rel="stylesheet" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.3.1/fullcalendar.print.css" type="text/css">-->
       <script src="assets/plugins/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
       <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.3.1/fullcalendar.js"></script>
       <script>
            moment().format();

            function httpGet(url) {
                var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlHttp.open("GET", url, false);
                xmlHttp.send(null);
                return xmlHttp.responseText;
            }

            $(document).ready(function () {

                // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

                //var eventsArray = JSON.parse(httpGet("Schedule.php"));

                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    // put your options and callbacks here
                    //timezone: 'America/Denver',
                    header: {
                        left:   '',
                        center: 'title',
                        right:  ''
                    },
                    theme:true,
                    events: [
                        {
                            "title":"Washer & Dryer",
                            "editable":false,
                            "start":"2017-04-09T00:30:00-0600",
                            "end":"2017-04-09T06:30:00-0600",
                            "img_loc":"washer.png"
                        },
                        {
                            "title":"Dishwasher",
                            "editable":false,
                            "start":"2017-04-09T02:56:00-0600",
                            "end":"2017-04-09T04:56:00-0600",
                            "img_loc":"dishwasher.jpg"
                        }
                    ],
                    defaultView: "agendaDay"
                })

            });

        </script>
        <style type='text/css'>
            #calendar {
            width: 900px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='calendar'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: screenshot of issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an `href` attribute instead of an `src` in the `<link>` tag that references the fullcalendar stylesheet. Your fourth line should look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.3.1/fullcalendar.min.css" type="text/css" />
```

Demo:
http://jsbin.com/tojohiwuke/1/edit?html,output
(I also changed jquery to use a CDN in my example.)

Comment: Thanks!  I'm more of a backend developer and sometimes miss little things like this.  I'll try this once I get back to my laptop this evening and update then.